# PyQt/Pyside - Create & Connect Dynamically - capturing function and arguments in lambda

Tags: python, lambda, pyqt, pyside, getattr

I'm trying to recreate the windows note pad.

I'm currently messing with the `QMenuBar`

I made a dictionary with all the menus and actions it will have in the following pattern:

```
menus = {'File':[['New', 'Ctrl+n'],
                 ['Open', 'Ctrl+o'],
                 ['Save', 'Ctrl+s'],
                 ['Save as...', None],
                 'Separator', 
                 # and so on
```

Then I iterate over that dict, and created the menus and actions successfully and stored them in a second dictionary.

Now I'm trying to connect each `action[new, open, save, …]` to a instance method of the same name.

I'm doing like so:

```
for action in menus[m]:
    action = menu.addAction(action[0])

    if action[1]:
        action.setShortcut(QKeySequence(action[1]))

    if isinstance(action, QAction):
        fname = action[0].lower() 
        # and some other string manipulations
        func = getattr(self,fname)
        action.triggered.connect(lambda arg=action: func(arg))
```

It connects successfully, but if I try to use any of the actions it does nothing.

I had previously connected actions using lambda functions, but this is the first time I'm using `getattr()` and lambda together.

Comment: Don't use `__getattribute__`: use `func = getattr(self, fname)`.

Comment: Wasn't aware of the difference between those two.

Comment: Just as `arg=action` needs to be bound, so does `func` - since that, too, changes each time through the loop.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Found my mistake:

Problem was that`func` was getting overwritten on every iteration over `menus`.

fixed it by changing:

```
action.triggered.connect(lambda arg=action:func(arg))
```

to

```
action.triggered.connect(lambda f=func,arg=a:f(arg))
```

The latter works because a reference to `func` is stored is taken immediately by default argument in lambda.